# JavaScript Condition evaluates to false?

Tags: javascript, numbers

I am currently trying to get familiar with JavaScript through solving the Project Euler tasks. In the following snippet, I am trying to get the sum of all even fibonacci numbers below 4.000.000.

```
var sum = 0;
var fibNums = [1, 2];
for (var i = 2; fibNums[i] < 4000000; i++) {
    fibNums[i] = fibNums[i - 1] + fibNums[i - 2];
    sum += fibNums[i] % 2 == 0 ? fibNums[i] : 0;
}
console.log(sum);
```

My problem is that `fibNums[i] < 4000000` evaluates to false, even on the first run. How does that come?

Comment: There is no `fibNums[2]`.

Comment: Why in the world the question is upvoted? I see negligence in this not a wonderful question. Besides knowing that index starts with `0` has beeen the case since the time of C or C++. I feel that this is absolute negligence

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal I know that indexes start with 0, i am just not familiar with javascript. Normally i work with c# which means i actually get a out of range exception for problems like that.

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal [Not always indexes start with 0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages_%28array%29#Array%5Fsystem%5Fcross-reference%5Flist).

Comment: Well what I meant here is this question is definitely not worth an upvote.. If you had even tried looking up google you'd find not less than 1000 examples. So I think you get the point. As far as your domain is concerned I see that even there indexes start with 0

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal i googled. My problem was not specificly about indexes, more about why the condition evaluates to false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*In short:* `(fibNums[i = 2] === undefined)`, whereas `(undefined < 40000 === false)`.

*Longer:*

You start your `for` loop with `var i = 2`, while `fibNums` array contains only 2 elements and has indexes starting with `0`. Hence, `fibNums[2]` will be `undefined`. In JavaScript `undefined` is never less than a number, as when you compare any number with `undefined` it will always be `false`.

Comment: So that means undefined equals to false in javascript?

Comment: @MuhammadUsman No, it means that whenever you compare `undefined` to a number, the result is always `false`.

Comment: Ahhh, okay that makes sense! Thank you, that helped.

Comment: If "undefined is always less than a number", why does `undefined < 40000` return `false`?

Comment: Note that both `undefined < 40000` and `undefined > 40000` return `false`. Comparing numbers with `undefined` is meaningless, so it returns `false` in all cases.

Comment: @Barmar That's what I've just included in the answer. And that works with `undefined == 0` as well.

Comment: You've got it wrong. `undefined` becomes `NaN`, not 0 or some arbitrary number. This is why both `<` and `>` operators yield false.

Comment: @SalmanA I never said that "`0` or some arbitrary number becomes `NaN`". Obviously both `0` and `42` *are* numbers and are not `Not-A-Number`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var sum = 0;
var fibNums = [1, 2, 0];

for (var i = 2;fibNums[i] < 4000000; i++) {
    fibNums[i] = fibNums[i-1] + fibNums[i-2];
    sum += fibNums[i] % 2 == 0 ? fibNums[i] : 0;
    fibNums.push(fibNums[i]); 
}

alert(sum);
```

Comment: Won't it just fail on the next iteration?

Comment: Instead of pushing a duplicate of `fibnums[i]`, couldn't you just test `fibnums[i-1] < 4000000`?